# Magit popup set height automatically

Tags: magit, window

When the `magit-commit-popup` window opens, there are one or two lines that are just below the screen. Calling `fit-window-to-buffer` in the popup buffer fixes the problem, but I would like to automate the process.

However, none of the following seems to work:

```
(add-hook 'magit-popup-mode-hook #'fit-window-to-buffer)
(add-hook 'magit-create-buffer-hook #'fit-window-to-buffer)
(add-hook 'magit-popup-help-mode-hook #'fit-window-to-buffer)
(add-hook 'magit-refresh-popup-buffer-hook #'fit-window-to-buffer)
```

Is there some hook that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally that does not happen and I suspect your frame is very narrow in height. If you want to keep using such a narrow frame, then you have two options.

1. The window is displayed using `(display-buffer buffer magit-popup-display-buffer-action)`. By adjusting `magit-popup-display-buffer-action` you should be able to accomplish what you want, but that might involve reading [Action Functions for display-buffer](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Display-Action-Functions.html#Display-Action-Functions) and related nodes.
2. Since you already know `fit-window-to-buffer` gets the job done, you can also just stick to that, and `magit-popup-mode-hook` should work for that.

   That hook is actually an abnormal hook and should be named `magit-popup-mode-functions`, but it is obsolete and I won't rename it. Because it is an abnormal hook (a hook that calls the functions with arguments), you have to think about the arguments and wrap `fit-window-to-buffer` accordingly.

   This is how it is called: `(run-hook-with-args 'magit-popup-setup-hook val def)`.